# Storing and retrieving data from MySQL or other databases

Tags: iphone, ios

I've been researching now for couple of days about this matter but with no luck.
I am learning iOS development with the plan of developing iPhone app mainly. Now this app will mimic the behaviour of my PHP site.

The question: Can I interact from my iPhone app directly with my tables to load and/or insert new data? if not mySQL then which database is used to host the data for CRUD operations? JSON objects? if yes, then how?

As you can see I am really unaware of the way and hope that some light should be shed on storing and retreving data from existing database or what I need to host new database to use with iPhone.

Comment: For beginner i would suggest using SQLite. Its a lightweight database for handheld devices.
To learn more about sqlite commands use this link.. http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html

You can create SQLite database by using a SQLite Database browser(GUI Tool) available for free.

Comment: import sqlite3 database onto ur project. And for more see this link.http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IPhone_Database_Implementation_using_SQLite

Answer (score 1):

The "best" and easiest way (for me anyway) is to use CoreData.

CoreData is a data management system. You set up some objects and relationships in it and then interact with those (use fetch requests to retrieve them and stuff).

CoreData then manages a datastore (most often a SQLite DB) which it uses to store the objects and relationships etc...

Using CoreData removes the necessity of a DBA and a lot of the complex DB logic and stuff.

A good tutorial to look at is this one...

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-core-data/

I bought this book though...

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-Core-Data-Professional-Apress/dp/1430236566/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1358773284&sr=1-2

and found it extremely useful for everything from starting out to the more advanced stuff.

When used properly, CoreData makes it VERY easy to use and manipulate persistent data.

Comment: Are you sure CoreData is 'most often' used with MySQL?  By default it uses SQLite.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, was distracted when typing :D Corrected, thanks.

Comment: But Where is coredata storing the information on how is it being hosted? I am asking because the data hosted in my database should be accessed by all users of my application anywhere

Comment: Huh? You mean for storage on a server somewhere or on the device itself?

Comment: server mate so that I different users can access it. for example: user  login screen in app...user enters credentials...I need to cross validate that user details with database record

Comment: Ah, then this is nothing to do with iOS. You need to be asking about PHP and MySQL or some such combination. This will then need to expose some web services that deal in JSON or something. Then your iOS app can consume these services.

Comment: Yes I was researching about JSON yesterday and it seems like the best way to handle the iOS app interfacing with PHP. I will most certainly give it a go with some Sqlite

Comment: iOS can take any valid JSON and turn it into iOS objects NSDictionary and NSArray so you don't have to parse the JSON yourself you just deal with the objects.

Answer (score 1):

YES, You can interact from your iPhone app directly with your tables to load and/or insert new data; Check the next tutorial - interact with your MySQL/PHP server http://www.scott-sherwood.com/ios-5-uistoryboards-a-practical-example/

Answer (score 0):

CoreData is good but limits to access to just iDevices.

I use couchdb, means a copy is stored in the cloud with auto syncing between cloud and devices allowing for web updates and also Android

Comment: I guess that is something to think about. Just a side note, CoreData can also be used for Mac OS X app too. Not just for iOS.